# Need to specify full URL in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, wampserver, errordocument

I have the following line in my .htaccess file and it works.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/error.php?code=404
```

When I change it to either of these it doesn't work anymore (don't know which is correct):

```
ErrorDocument 404 error.php?code=404
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?code=404
```

The .htaccess file and error.php are in the same directory. Why is this happening?

Note: I'm on Wampserver

FULL .HTACCESS FILE

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/error.php?code=404
```

Comment: Show us your `.htaccess` fully.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because of the query string.

When you don't supply a full URL to the `ErrorDocument` directive, Apache treats is as a local file path relative to `DocumentRoot`. Slightly confusingly, you do need to use the leading `/` even though it is technically a relative path.

Now, what you want to do is actually not as simple as it may seem on the face of it. Because you are now dealing with a local path, the query string portion no longer has a special meaning, and will be treated as a literal part of the file name - and obviously the file is not called `error.php?code=404`, it's just called `error.php`. Thankfully though, it is possible with a little bit of messing around, because `ErrorDocument` does generate an internal request which is passed through the standard routing engine. What we will need here is a little bit of `mod_rewrite` magic.

Try the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?error-([0-9]+)\.php$ /error.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This assumes that your .htaccess and error.php files both reside in the `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: What happened instead? Check the Apache logs... Also if you show the location of your files relative to document root I can tailor the above code to your situation.

Comment: It just looks to have ignored the rule. The apache logs say that the file was not found (I tried localhost/something and it tries to find something.php, but that's normal).

Comment: @RichardG Can you show your file system layout and where these files reside relative to DocumentRoot?

Comment: The files are stored in Wampservers www folder

Comment: So they are all just in `www` and not e.g. `www/subfolder`?

Comment: @RichardG And the .htaccess file is definitely being processed and the PHP script works? What happens if you go to `http://yoursite.com/error.php?code=404` and `http://yoursite.com/error-404.php`?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, 404 (like 403, 502, ...) code is a HTTP code so it could be logic that the instruction ErrorDocument, which reference to HTTP process in your case, needs a http:// instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Using DaveRandom's solution, I simply added the **R** flag to RwriteRule and it works.

Try this configuration:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?error-([0-9]+)\.php$ /error.php?code=$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

For me it works on Apache 2.4.12